# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql-server, web-services, exception, timeout

all
I am trying to resolve issue. where situation is,
There is asp.net webservice. webservice is connected with the sql server. created for receiving the data. but while requesting to the webmethod, even in browser i am getting exception :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

AS per my understanding this must be issue about delaying in response from the server.Or due to time complexity in data fetching process in the method. I know we can specify the timeout for the sql command. but I don't have code access to change it. in short it is out of my scope to make change int he webservice code. how can i resolve this issue without editing any code. I can edit the web.config of webservice. but not code. please guide me.

**Edited:**
This issue is still there. but I am getting this issue on test server only. but on production server, it is running perfectly. I want to simulate this and want to resolve it on test server. because of this i am unable to proceed for next operation which is not present on the production server. why should this arriving here (on test server).

On test server i am changing the sql server name.
Because of this difference, we can conclude it should not be the issue in code. it must be issue /somewhere need setting in database side to define timeout or may be different . please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna have to get someone who can change the code, increase the `CommandTimeout` (or set it to `0` for unlimited), and, more importantly, find out why the query takes so long.

Comment: Thanks Soren, but it is out of my scope to change the code. else any hotfix for the same?

Answer (score 0):

If we set the timeout value to zero that means we are making sure that the operating will competed at any cost.

Comment: You can't change the command timeout from the `web.config`, though, as far as I know. (The connection timeout is unrelated.)

Comment: Take an example of very long operating of sql query and mention the time which is less then the time taken to complete the sql opearation. Now on the other hand perform the same operation by setting the timeout to zero Solve the problem at run time

Comment: Ok, it must missunderstanding by me,perhaps. I thought the change of timeout parameter in connection string may impact over this exception. indeed it is out of my hand to change in code. any other way to identify this ?

Comment: Run your SQL in query analizer and see how many minutes it takes.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, perhaps i could access sql server.it is also out of my reach